# REST API to webhooks C#

Tags: c#, webhooks

I am newbie to webhooks and doing google search is confusing me more lol.

I designed and implemented a HTTP POST rest API end point using .NET framework. I am able to consume this endpoint using postman without any problem.
http://localhost:44309/custom/process
{"name":"testing"}
I am trying to write a web hook to consume that. My network is private, how can i register the endpoint and what is the best approach to implement and test webhook receiver?

Comment: https://ngrok.com/

Comment: Unfornatelly, my network is private and does not allow me

Comment: Wait, in what way? ngrok is designed to expose a private network endpoint

Comment: i am not able to go to this site

Comment: ...you can access StackOverflow and Google though? Interesting... corporate network settings? Talk to admin?

Comment: This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://ngrok.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219830/discussion-between-mikey-and-coolbots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your endpoint publicly visible; a common tool for that is [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which is designed for this purpose, and has a free tier.

Comment: this web wook will be used internally and will never be exposed to the public

Comment: Ok, then what's the issue? deploy it to an internal testing server, or open up your firewall

Comment: @CoolBots I have almost the same question. I heard ngrok is only good for testing purposes. Shall I go with the AWS EC2 for a larger scale enterprise level?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian yeah, ngrok is a testing tool, definitely not a permanent solution, especially in an enterprise application setting

Comment: @CoolBots, was hoping to by pass that...thanks for the informmation